# Can't preview smoke simulation on Blender 2.82

Tags: smoke-simulation

Whenever I add a Quick Smoke effect, I can't preview it on the viewport unless I bake it.

And Yes, I added the Smoke Domain on the object.

I've seen tutorials like this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VmRqlsuSvsw
and this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_IDBfQnttiE that clearly shows the possibility of previewing the smoke before baking it.

I'm using Blender on a Mac with AMD GPU. I would guess that this is something related to OpenGL, as thoroughly explained here - [Why is the smoke preview not showing in Blender's viewport?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/32786/why-is-the-smoke-preview-not-showing-in-blenders-viewport) but that's for Windows.

Does anyone have any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fixed it. The default Cache Type is set to "Modular". In order to see the Smoke preview in the viewport, it's necessary to switch it to "Replay". 
[image]

Big thanks to Pablo Vazquez that found this solution on Twitter.

Answer (score 2):

1. Select smoke domain
2. Open *Physics* tab
3. Check *Cache Type*

If you want to stay on *Modular* in settings click *Bake Data* or change to *Replay*.

[image]