# No Smoke on mac

Tags: smoke-simulation, osx

I run blender 2.8 on my MacBook. However when I try to run a quick smoke simulation, nothing shows in the viewport. Why can’t I see the simulation? I have an object and a domain as default. Please help. Running 2.82a. Anyone??

Comment: Please be more specific. Blender 2.82 has a new smoke simulation are you using Blender 2.82 or higher.

Comment: Im using version 2.82a

Comment: Running 2.82a, but it doesnt work.

Comment: @KristianBoserup Welcome to Blender StackExchange. For us to be able to answer your question most efficiently, you will need to be more specific. As they say, a picture speaks a thousand words- please consider uploading a screenshot, or even the file itself.

Comment: Just found this solution and it works: I had to change the cache to replay and now the smoke is there. https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/168082/96492

Answer (score 0):

Try baking the data in your Smoke Domain (blend file here: [image]):

[image]

Comment: Can someone upload a simple default smoke scene? Then I can test if it is my scene that bugs

Comment: added to my answer