# Monkey won't smoke or burn

Tags: objects

I've just started with Blender, following Blender Guru's beginner tutorial lesson 1.
I can get the monkey mesh and the smoke box but when I click "play" nothing happens. The monkey won't burn either.
I've tried selecting the monkey and not the smoke, the smoke and not the monkey, both of them and neither. None of it makes a difference.
Blender version 2.82.7
How can I get Blender to do what it ought to?

Comment: Suggest add a link to the tutorial and your blend using: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ to your q.

Comment: Hi :). All the answers are fine, you can also download [Blender 2.81](https://download.blender.org/release/) and it will work the same as BlenderGuru's.

Comment: related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/170746/no-smoke-on-mac/170781#170781

Answer (score 1):

In Blender 2.82, the fluids simulation system has been replaced by Mantaflow which default's caching methods, "modular" doesn't bake on playback. It instead allows you to bake different settings of your simulation individually, which saves a lot of time when you're tweaking your simulation.
You have to manually start the baking via the domain's panel. You can also change the caching method, but honestly the new "modular" is usually a better option).

I'd suggest you follow tutorials specifically made for Blender ≥2.82 or with "mantaflow" specified in the title.

Answer (score 0):

So blender 2.82 has this mantaflow fluid simulation system which is a bit different. How you could go about it which worked for me is that you can add the smoke even if it is not visible, and save the file. The close and reopen the file that you save and bake it. It should work fine then.
Hope this helps...

Comment: OK, thanks for the answers. I don't actually care about burning the monkey, I was more concerned that there was something wrong with what I was doing.