# Blender 2.82 simulation interface unlock?

Tags: interface, baking, fluid-simulation

upgraded lastly from Blender 2.79 to 2.82.  With 2.79 I used Blender to do fluid simulation.  Now trying the same with the newer version.  Unfortunately, the new version locks the screen during simulation baking so no other work is possible.  The old version allowed even to preview already baked steps, which was very-very comfortable!

Am I missing something in the new version, or is it really not possible to use Blender during baking anymore?

Comment: Does this help? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/167526/cant-preview-smoke-simulation-on-blender-2-82