# Why my domain is rendering just like a box in preview?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, 3d-view, smoke-simulation, mantaflow

Even when I setup the simulation using 'quick smoke' I always get just a box in the viewport:

[image: this is render preview]

[image: view port display]

I tried to re-install and reset the settings and tried to use many different volume materials. In many tutorials they recommend to add a principled volume and everything should be fine but in my case I always get the box and I don't understand what I'm missing here.

**Q:** Why my domain is rendering like a box in preview whenever I do smoke simulation?

Comment: So you are opening a brand new blender file with a default cube and do quick smoke and you see just a box in rendered view? is that right? if yes, can you please provide your blend file and tell us, which version u r using?

Comment: I don't know why but after reinstalling blender 2.91 smoke is visible in the render view after I increased the density. but the render animation preview shows the same cube shape as the above image.  [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=2QEXyEEX" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/2QEXyEEX/) here is the file

Comment: now I'm suddenly facing another issue with the same file path tracing in render view flickering.

Comment: can you please check whether your cache path is ok? [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ynfwh.png

Comment: Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/167526/cant-preview-smoke-simulation-on-blender-2-82

Comment: @brockmann: his blend file is already on replay...did not help... :(

Comment: Good to know @Chris

Comment: @Bobbybharadwaj: i tried. I am sorry, i have no idea why this happened.

Comment: I'm actually a beginner so somethings I'm not sure about but my cache path is ok.

Comment: thanks for helping at least now render view is kinda ok. The only problem is rendered preview I guess not a big issue :)